# Resize Double Dots (Something like that)

Tags: c#, integer, double

I tried to resize the dots of the number (I don't really know how to explain it so I'll demonstrate it)

```
    static void Main()
    {
        WebRequest Req;
        WebResponse Res;
        Req = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://download.skype.com/0dce4e856bdf8239787df5c367298d54/partner/59/SkypeSetupFull.exe");
        Res = Req.GetResponse();
        double fileSize = Res.ContentLength * 100 / 1024;
        // Console.WriteLine((fileSize)e-5); - Not Possible
        Console.WriteLine(4405559e-5);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I'm trying to make the filesize (which its lets say 4405559) to 44.05559, any idea how I can do it?

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're looking for division:

```
Console.WriteLine(fileSize / 10000.0);
```